# Create "group function"

Tags: sql

I want to create a group function on my site and I'm wondering what the best way to do this would be? would i be best to create two tables groups and group_members? im fairly new to sql so im not so sure.

im thinking this:

```
groups
  group_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  group_name varchar(32) NOT NULL
```

```
group_members
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  group_id int(11) NOT NULL
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL
```

```
users
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment
  username varchar(24) NOT NULL
  password varchar(32) NOT NULL
```

would that be the best? or is there a better way?

Cheers boys

EDIT: CHECK MY LAST MESSAGE FOR ANOTHER QUESTION :)

Comment: As a side note: You should not store actual passwords. Do some research on Hash Functions and Salting Hashed Passwords.

Comment: i do use both salt and hash. what makes you think i dont??

Comment: because you have a varchar(32) column called password instead of a hash?

Answer (score 2):

That is how I would do it.

Another option would be to put a group_id column in the users table, but if you do that you'd be restricting yourself to only one group per user.  The way you are doing it allows a many to many relationship, which I think is the best route to go :o)

Answer (score 1):

> would that be the best?

Exactly.

It's a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).